# Import txt file into excel, split string where spaces and place each word in cell

Tags: excel, vba, text, ms-office

I have a .txt file that contain thousands of words all are separated by spaces. I want to add all those words into an excel spread sheet. each word in a cell so the result would be a large column of words. Following are examples:

myText.txt

```
Candle Man great Hazard change Length Boring
```

myExcel.xlsx

```
------
Candle
------
Man
------
great
------
Hazard
------
change
------
Length
------
Boring
------
```

Comment: If there aren't too many words then you could do this by importing the data into Excel with a space delimiter (one row with multiple columns), then copy, paste special - pivot to convert it into a single column with multiple rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could just use transpose in excel if you only have single words..?

Import your data (either by import or copy and paste)

[image]

Then you use "Text to Columns" and choose "Delimited".

[image]

The words are separated by space, so we choose space as delimiter, press Finish.

[image]

You should now have each word separated by a single cell. Something like this. Copy this range.

[image]

Click in cell you want to paste into and choose paste (right click or go to Home-> Paste -> Transpose.

[image]

You should now have a result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the feature Text to column. Paste the text, select the cell has text. In the ribbon go `Data => Text to columns => Delimited => Click Next => Tick Space => Finish`. Next time you copy text, Excel will automatically separate them into columns as well. So remember uncheck it if you don't need the functionality anymore. If you want rows then you can copy, paste special transpose the columns.